# Detect when UIViewController is no longer presenting a view controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, key-value-observing

I would like to observe a view controller that is presenting a view controller to determine when it stops presenting it.

I thought about trying KVO, which I'm not terribly familiar with:

```
[observedVC addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(presentedViewController)) options:0 context:NULL];
```

And then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"Change: %@", keyPath);
}
```

But I am not seeing this get called. Is there a better way to go about this? I'm working on an SDK so I don't necessarily have any control over the observedVC.

Comment: The proper way to do this is through delegation. If the Presenting view controller is the delegate of the Presented view controller, you will kow when the presented view is gone because the Presenting view controller would have dismissed it.

Comment: @rmp it works this way only for simple apps, in real life enterprise you'll meet complex navigation where non-universal solutions and tight code coupling will blow up your project